# Standard phrases for software translation

Tags: internationalization, translation, usability

Where can I find a list of standardized phrases and vocabularies that one should use to translate software in the languages french, english and german?

I could imagine that Qt, the GNU project or DIN provides such tables, but I could not find it yet.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably something called Translation Memory. Please take a look at [Launchpad](https://translations.launchpad.net/). Ubuntu has tons of translations for programs and most of them are high quality translations.

On a side note, please be careful with "standard" translations. Things like "OK", "Cancel", standard menus ("File", "Edit", "View", "Help") could be translated this way, but please keep in mind that many words could be translated differently, depending on the context.
For them adding you project (provided that it is open source) to the crowd-sourcing sites like Launchpad (there are quite a few more) may make sense. If your application is useful, somebody will translate it to his/her language, that's for sure.